# MLE for $\frac{\theta x + 1}{2}$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

Consider a variable $X$ which is modeled by the probability density $p(X|\theta)=\displaystyle\frac{\theta x + 1}{2}$ for $-1\leq x \leq 1$. Find:

(a) The MLE of $\theta$.

(b) The MLE of $\hat\theta$.

(c) The bias of the MLE.

---

Okay, so for part (a):

$\begin{align}
f(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n | \theta) &= \displaystyle\frac{n+\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(\theta X_i)}{2} \\ \Rightarrow \text{log }L(\theta) &= \text{log }\displaystyle\frac{n}{2} + \text{log }\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{log}\big(\theta X_i\big)
\end{align}$

Is this correct so far? If not, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by the MLE of $\hat{\theta}$?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is worthwhile recognising that your density is only a valid density function (non-negative over the support) for $-1 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 1$.  The log-likelihood within this parameter range is:

$$\ell_\boldsymbol{x}(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln (1 + \theta x_i) \quad \quad \text{for all } -1 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 1.$$

Hence, for all $-1 < \theta < 1$ we have:

$$\frac{d \ell_\boldsymbol{x}}{d \theta}(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{1 + \theta x_i} \quad \quad \quad \frac{d^2 \ell_\boldsymbol{x}}{d \theta^2}(\theta) = - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{(1 + \theta x_i)^2} \leqslant 0.$$

From this we can see that the log-likelihood function is strictly concave for all $\boldsymbol{x} \neq \boldsymbol{0}$ (which means that it is strictly concave with probability one under the specified density).  Hence, the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ is the (almost surely) unique solution to the critical-point equation:

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{1 + \hat{\theta} x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n ( \hat{\theta} + r_i )^{-1} \quad \quad \quad r_i = \frac{1}{x_i}.$$

This equation had no closed form solution, and so it must be solved numerically.  It can be obtained using the Newton-Raphson iterative method, with recursive equation:

$$\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \hat{\theta}_{n} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ( \hat{\theta}_{n} + r_i )^{-1}}{\sum_{i=1}^n ( \hat{\theta}_{n} + r_i )^{-2} }.$$

Answer (score 0):

The Likelihood is computed wrongly.

P(X1,X2,...,Xn|θ) = P(X1/θ)P(X2/θ)....P(Xn/θ)
                 = (θ*X1+1)/2*(θ*X2+1)/2.....(θ*Xn+1)/2

Log P(X1,X2,...,Xn|θ) = Σ log((θ*Xi+1)/2)

You can proceed from here on. The mistake you made is took the likelihood as a sum instead of product before taking log.

Comment: Thank you. So, just to clarify, deriving $\sum_{i=1}^n \text{log }\displaystyle\frac{\theta X_i + 1}{2}$ would lead to $\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\frac{X_i}{2}$, which would be my final answer?

Comment: No thats not right. The derivative  would be ∑Xi/(θ*Xi+1).  Setting   ∑Xi/(θ*Xi+1) = 0 will give the MLE of θ which unfortunately doesn't have a closed form solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then isn't it extremely complicated to find the MLE of $\hat\theta$ if the MLE of $\theta$ doesn't have a closed form solution?

Comment: True..it doesn't have a closed form solution. However different other numerical iterative methods can be applied to form a solution.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand what those methods would be. What would be the best way to solve for $\hat\theta$ in $\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\frac{X_i}{\theta X_i + 1}$, then?

Comment: You can use Numerical Methods such as Newton Rapson,Fixed Point Iteration,etc to derive a solution. Sharing a link to an article which would give you some clarity http://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2613&context=etd .. Hope this helps.